# Dynamically Adding Columns to a DBIx::Class ResultSet

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I have a `DBIx::Class` object representing an eBay auction. The underlying table has a description column which contains a lot of data. The description column is almost never used, so it's not included in the `DBIx::Class` column list for that table.  That way, most queries don't fetch the auction description data.

I do, however, have one script that needs this column.  In this one case, I want to access the contents of the description column as I would any other column:

```
$auction->description
```

How can I accomplish this without forcing all other queries to fetch the description column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In older versions of `DBIx::Class` (not sure of the version number), the following used to work:

```
my $rs = $schema->resultset('Auctions');
my $lots = $rs->search(
   undef,
   { '+select' => 'description', '+as' => 'description' },
);
```

That doesn't seem to work for row updates under modern versions of `DBIx::Class`.  Trying that with an update

```
$auction->update({ description => '...'})
```

under `DBIx::Class` 0.08123 gives the following error: "DBIx::Class::Relationship::CascadeActions::update(): No such column description at ..."

Assuming that the script needing the extra column is running in its own process.  You can do something like this:

```
my $rs = $schema->resultset('Auctions');
$rs->result_source->add_columns('description');
YourApp::Schema::Lots->add_columns('description');
YourApp::Schema::Lots->register_column('description');
```

Of course, that's a global change.  After adding the column, other code in the same process will start fetching the `description` column in queries.  Not to mention, it's kind of ugly.